# Installing windows 7 into a win 8 computer (partitions)

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, partitioning, 64-bit

I'm installing windows 7 from a dvd, everything went fine but when i formatted the partition i wanted to install win 7 into, it says ''windows can't be installed on this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style''. My computer has win 8 (64-bit), but I'm switching into win 7 (64-bit).

Comment: I would delete the current partition information then attempt to install Windows 7.  You should clearly backup your personal files and record your Windows 8 OEM key because it will be difficult to do after you install Windows 7 should you ever decide to switch.

Comment: I agree with Ramhound.. Delete the partition entirely before installing. Windows 7 wont continue if there is another operating system on the drive..

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 x64 supports booting to GPT disks. According to the TechNet article ‘[Installing Windows to an EFI-Based computer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744321.aspx)’, you need to launch the Windows EFI Boot Loader on the Installation Disk. If you have the option to boot to EFI DVD, that’s what you need to do to get Windows 7 X64 to install on a GPT disk. The alternative is, as Ramhound suggests, delete all partitions and install normally which will format the disk as MBR.

Hope this helps,